# Lazy evaluation of `which` function arguments?

Tags: r

If there are multiple boolean expressions as arguments to the `which` function, are they evaluated lazily?

For example:

`which(test1 & test2)`

If `test1` returns false, then `test2` is not evaluated as the compound expression will be false anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `if` there can be efficiency gains as a result of that behavior. It is documented to work that way, and I don't think it is due to lazy evaluation. Even if you "force()-ed" that expression it would still only evaluate a series of &'s until it had a single FALSE. See this help page:

```
?Logic
```

@XuWang probably deserved the credit for emphasizing the difference between "&" and "&&". The "&" operator works on vectors and returns vectors. The "&&" operator acts on scalars (actually vectors of length==1) and returns a vector of length== 1. When offered a vector or length >1 as either side of the arguments, it will work on only the information in the first value of each and emit a warning. It is only the "&&" version that does what is being called "lazy" evaluation. You can see that hte "&" operator is not acting in a "lazy fashion with a simepl test:

```
 fn1 <- function(x) print(x)
 fn2 <- function(x) print(x)
 x1 <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10, replace=TRUE)

 fn1(x1) & fn2(x1)  # the first two indicate evaluation of both sides regardless of first value
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: True about `if`. Considering a vector, matrix, etc., `if` won't do. I suppose `while` may. However, efficiency, aside I believe R does evaluate lazily (i.e. until the single FALSE expression).

Comment: as `?Logic` says, I think what you call lazy evaluation occurs when `&&` is used, but I don't think it's necessarily true when `&` is used.

Comment: The point of lazy evaluation of function arguments is (more or less) to avoid work.  But since the contents of logical expressions such as `which` and `if` don't return anything (only the logical function itself does), there's really no point to evaluating something when the result of the full expression is already known.

Comment: If that's your definition of lazy then you are right and it is the behavior that is documented.

Comment: @XuWang I didn't even know there was an `&&` operator. Just like Java then. I'd +1 if I could. Cheers.